# SQL recursive level 1 supervisee staff

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I am stack again. I want to get all the supervisors who supervise staff less than 1.

In my result I miss one supervisor so I think my Query is wrong.

```
  SELECT   c.EmpID,c.name,c.gender,c.salary,COUNT(*) AS superviseeStaff_Count
  FROM     staff c  INNER JOIN staff u ON c.EmpID = u.supervisorFk 
           And  c.position='Supervisor' 
  GROUP BY c.EmpID,c.name,c.gender, c.salary
  HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
```

Result:
38  Anna-Isabell Green  F   32000.0 1 
42  Winston Hughes  M   22000.0 1
61  Sally Thatcher  F   36000.0 1

I miss Supervisor with empID 48.

I tried with `With` clause and same but no effect on results.

Staff table looks like:
EmpID,name,gender,salary,supervisorFk(Foreignkey of supervisor),BranchFK,position

```
--Data:

delete from Staff;

    --  data for table Staff   
    --  ---------------------

    -- 67 Employees 


    insert into Staff values ( 1, 'Robert King'      ,'M', 143000.0,NULL, 'B002', 'Director');
    insert into Staff values ( 2, 'Rafael McDonalds' ,'M',  72000.0, 1,'B001', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values ( 3, 'John White'       ,'M',  60000.0, 1,'B003', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values ( 4, 'Susan Brand'      ,'F',  55000.0, 1,'B004', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values ( 5, 'Cathy Brown'      ,'F',  32000.0, 2,'B001', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values ( 6, 'Claire Dujeune'   ,'F',  79000.0, 1,'B010', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values ( 7, 'Patty Summer'     ,'F',  23000.0, 2,'B001', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values ( 8, 'Mary Fleming'     ,'F',  43000.0, 1,'B011', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values (10, 'Anne Beech'       ,'F',  26000.0, 5,'B001', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (12, 'Paul Coplien'     ,'M',  27000.0, 3,'B003', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (13, 'David Ford'       ,'M',  41000.0, 1,'B012', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values (14, 'Mary Howe'        ,'F',  55000.0, 1,'B005', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values (15, 'Julie Lee'        ,'F',  34000.0, 3,'B003', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (16, 'Aaron Young'      ,'M',  74000.0, 1,'B013', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values (17, 'Albert Thomson'   ,'M',  25000.0,13,'B012', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (21, 'Alexander Reynolds','M', 37000.0, 5,'B001', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (18, 'Christine McDonalds','F',38000.0, 4,'B004', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (19, 'Elisa Pinkerton'  ,'F',  36000.0,16,'B013', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (20, 'Eric Montgomery'  ,'M',  33000.0, 7,'B001', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (22, 'Edward Robinson'  ,'M',  28000.0, 7,'B001', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (23, 'Jesse Owens'      ,'M',  34000.0, 4,'B004', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (25, 'Johnatan Hunter'  ,'M',  45000.0, 1,'B014', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values (26, 'Lenita Kennedy'   ,'F',  56000.0, 1,'B009', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values (27, 'Lisa Miller'      ,'F',  34000.0,25,'B014', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (28, 'Lilly Jennings'   ,'F',  36000.0,14,'B005', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (29, 'Rafaela Johnson'  ,'F',  23000.0,12,'B003', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (32, 'Harry Anderson'   ,'M',  40000.0,12,'B003', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (33, 'George Bailey'    ,'M',  73000.0, 1,'B006', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values (34, 'Salomon Beckett'  ,'M',  46000.0, 1,'B008', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values (35, 'Susan Armstrong'  ,'F',  28000.0,15,'B003', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (36, 'Rosa Hemingway'   ,'F',  30000.0,15,'B003', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (37, 'Martha McDonalds' ,'F',  31000.0,15,'B003', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (38, 'Anna-Isabell Green','F', 32000.0,33,'B006', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (39, 'Tina Hall-Becker' ,'F',  34000.0,18,'B004', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (40, 'Thomas Harrison'  ,'M',  42000.0, 1,'B007', 'Manager');
    insert into Staff values (42, 'Winston Hughes'   ,'M',  22000.0,40,'B007', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (44, 'Walter Jefferson' ,'M',  23000.0,18,'B004', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (45, 'Zara Newton'      ,'F',  24000.0,23,'B004', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (46, 'Nina McDonalds'   ,'F',  25000.0,23,'B004', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (48, 'Carol Moore'      ,'M',  27000.0,40,'B007', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (51, 'Alexander Porter' ,'M',  29000.0,17,'B012', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (52, 'Maria Quasimodo'  ,'M',  30000.0,17,'B012', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (53, 'Bertrand Russel'  ,'M',  31000.0,34,'B008', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (54, 'Ashley Parker'    ,'M',  25500.0,28,'B005', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (55, 'John Stuart'      ,'M',  23500.0,28,'B005', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (56, 'Ruth Sanderss'    ,'F',  27700.0,19,'B013', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (57, 'Rafael Smith'     ,'M',  32000.0,19,'B013', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (58, 'Viola Rutherford' ,'F',  21000.0,27,'B014', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (59, 'Sammy Churchill'  ,'M',  22000.0,27,'B014', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (60, 'Miriam Thorne'    ,'F',  26000.0,27,'B014', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (61, 'Sally Thatcher'   ,'F',  36000.0,34,'B008', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (62, 'Larry Escott'     ,'M',  33000.0,26,'B009', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (63, 'William Spencer'  ,'M',  32000.0, 6,'B010', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (64, 'Diana Ashley-Bell','F',  38000.0, 8,'B011', 'Supervisor');
    insert into Staff values (65, 'Audrey Thorne'    ,'F',  25000.0,62,'B009', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (66, 'Paula Burns'      ,'F',  24000.0,62,'B002', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (67, 'Amanda Wallis'    ,'F',  23000.0,38,'B006', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (68, 'Patty Stokes'     ,'F',  22000.0,53,'B008', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (69, 'Holly Fields'     ,'F',  21500.0,53,'B008', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (70, 'Martha McCulloch' ,'F',  26000.0,61,'B008', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (71, 'Maurin Best'      ,'F',  22500.0,42,'B007', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (72, 'Martha McDonalds' ,'F',  23500.0,27,'B014', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (73, 'Barrigan' ,NULL,  23500.0,27,'B013', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (47, 'Naomi Campell'    ,'F',  26000.0,63,'B010', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (49, 'Tony McDonalds'   ,'M',  28000.0,63,'B010', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values (50, 'Margret McElroy'  ,'F',  29000.0,64,'B011', 'Assistant');
    insert into Staff values ( 9, 'Carl Maier'       ,'M',  31000.0,64,'B011', 'Assistant');
```

I am trying this but not working:

```
WITH Tree
AS (
SELECT
    EmpID,
    name,
    gender,
    salary,SupervisorFK,
    1 AS Level
   FROM staff
WHERE position='Supervisor'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    st.EmpID,
    st.name,
    st.gender,
    st.salary,st.SupervisorFK,
    level + 1
FROM Staff AS st
    JOIN Tree uh ON uh.EmpID = st.SupervisorFK    
)

SELECT * FROM Tree
```

Comment: Have you forgot to include your source data?

Comment: Nope the employee with EmpID exists

Comment: Have you forgot to include your source data **in your question here**? You show the result but we have no idea what your source data looked like.

Comment: Updated with table schmeta and source data plz see above hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple actually. In your source data, there are no employees with a `supervisorFk` value of 48, so Supervisor #48 (Carol Moore) has no employees. Since you're doing an `INNER JOIN` based on that foreign key, that record is never in the initial set. You don't even make it to the `HAVING` clause of `COUNT(*)=1` - the user isn't there to be counted.

Change that to a `LEFT JOIN` and make your `COUNT(*)<=1`, or add a record that has a `supervisorFk` of `48` and then you'll see the user.

Comment: its a task from university so the right result are staff with EmpID=38,42,48,61. pretty strange

Comment: I will clear this and post an solution if its avaible for others to find a solution for themself! Thanks!